# Join User ID to multiple columns

Tags: sql, join

Noob here.

Easiest way to join two tables 1) User ID to table 2) User ID's in multiple columns. Some columns may be Null or may be full across row per encounter.

**table MisPerson_Names**, columns:

- NameStored
- UnvUserID

**table EncounterUsers**, columns:

- UnvUserID1
- UnvUserID2
- UnvUserID3
- UnvUserID4

Expected Result:

| UnvUserID1 | NameStored1 | UnvUserID2 | NameStored2 | UnvUserID3 | Namestored3 | UnvUserID4 | Namestored4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Is there a better way than just:

```
SELECT 
  eu.UnvUserID1, mpn1.NameStored AS NameStored1,
  eu.UnvUserID2, mpn2.NameStored AS NameStored2,
  eu.UnvUserID3, mpn3.NameStored AS NameStored3,
  eu.UnvUserID4, mpn4.NameStored AS NameStored4
FROM EncounterUsers eu
LEFT JOIN MisPerson_Names mpn1 ON mpn1.UnvUserID = eu.UnvUserID1
LEFT JOIN MisPerson_Names mpn2 ON mpn2.UnvUserID = eu.UnvUserID2
LEFT JOIN MisPerson_Names mpn3 ON mpn3.UnvUserID = eu.UnvUserID3
LEFT JOIN MisPerson_Names mpn4 ON mpn4.UnvUserID = eu.UnvUserID4
```

Comment: Post data as text, not images.

Comment: Do you have control over the table structure?  Table 2 is modeled poorly.  Don't pre-pivot the data.  There should be one UnvUserID column.  So each row in Table 2 should be 0-4 (or 0-many) rows.

Comment: Making the image display on this page rather than behind the link doesn't fix the problem.  There is no way for a potential answerer to copy and paste the text to begin coding work.  Making the experts do all of the leg work will drive them away.

Comment: No there is no way to modify the table structure. Each column is a different provider type and the data is to massive to have multiple table joins on the same table.

I'm not sure on the image part. I've never posted here before. All it was was a image of an excel example of what the joined end result table would look like.

Comment: Write out the DML to create the two tables and present the expected results as a table (not an image).

Comment: you can use the SQL UNION clause to simplify your query and make it more readable.

Comment: No, the query shown in the request is already the straight-forward and simplest way to write the query. An alternative would be subqueries in the select clause. The suggestion to use `UNION (ALL)` instead would make the query only more complicated. What is your DBMS by the way? When asking SQL questions, always tag your request with your DBMS please.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The query you are showing is already the best option. You won't get it any more readable or faster.

There should be an index on `MisPerson_Names (UnvUserID)` of course, but that is most likely the case already, as the column should be the table's primary key, and most DBMS create a unique index on the primary key automatically.